# transferring parameters in C++

Tags: c++

can I have this snippet of the code:

```
C *pa1 = new C(c2);
```

and I transfer it to another function:

```
foo(pa1);
```

what exactly do I transfer actual pointer or its copy, thanks in advance
and can somebody give some info about in which cases info is copied, and in which I transfer actual pointer

declaration of foo:

```
foo(A const *pa)
```

Comment: I wrote a long explanation of the different argument semantics in a previous question that you might want to take a look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c/2139553#2139553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming foo is declared as:

```
void foo(C* p);
```

you are passing a copy of the pointer.

This means, if foo does this:

```
p = &some_other_object;
```

that change to the pointer won't be seen by the caller.

It also means we're copying the *pointer*, not the *thing pointed to*. If foo does this:

```
p->bar = "Smurf!"
```

pa1 in the caller will also see the change. For this reason, pointers are often used to implement a kind of pass-by-reference.

If foo were declared:

```
void foo(C*& p);
```

then p would be a reference to pa1, and changes to p would result in changes to pa1. Historically, this has also been implemented using pointers to pointers:

```
void foo(C** p);
```

in which case you call foo like this:

```
foo(&pa1);
```

and foo can do something like:

```
*p = &some_other_object;
```

to change what pa1 points to.

Comment: ok, thanks, but what if I want to transfer actual pointer? not its copy, do I need use two **?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by "transfer". If you want a function to be able to modify the pointer so the caller's pointer changes, then yes you do want C** instead of C*, and call foo(&pa1).

Comment: @camh: or `void foo( C*& p );` and there is no need to change the call.

Answer (score 1):

Since `pa1` is of type pointer-to-C, you are passing a pointer to C to the function `foo`. You are not copying the actual object.

To pass an object, you would need foo to take an object of type C and to dereference `pa1` when passing it:

```
void foo(C);
...
foo(*pa1);
```

Comment: The pointer is copied. In the function you call foo from, it holds a pointed to C (in pa1). In foo, it holds a pointer to C (in its actual argument). Hence the pointer is copied. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Since `pa1` is a pointer (as you have defined it as a `C *`), you are passing a pointer to the C object into `foo`.

That said, whether you are passing the pointer by value or by reference is unknown without seeing the declaration of `foo`.

Comment: can You give me please two declarations which will show me difference between these two methods of transferring in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
C *pa1;
```

object of type 'C*' is created on the stack (local variable pa1)

```
pa1 = new C(c2);
```

object of type 'C' is created on the heap, its address is returned into 'pa1' variable

```
foo(pa1)
```

We can say "object of type 'C*' (variable pa1) is passed by-value to function foo, the function gets a copy of the pointer",
But also "object of type 'C' (this one created on the heap) passed by-reference (through pointer) to function foo, no copy 'C' object is made.

To pass by-reference (without making a copy of an object) either c++ reference to the object can be used or pointer to the object. They act similar when going about function parameter passing, i.e all of 4 lines below gives the same effect, passing by-reference (these are const references, remove const keyword to be able to permanently modify the object by the foo function):

```
foo(const A *pa) { pa->DoSth(); } /*...*/ foo(some_pointer);
foo(const A *pa) { pa->DoSth(); } /*...*/ foo(&some_reference);
foo(const A &pa) { pa.DoSth(); } /*...*/ foo(*some_pointer);
foo(const A &pa) { pa.DoSth(); } /*...*/ foo(some_reference);
```